# Python - Efficient algorithm to compute edge adjacency matrix (line graph)

Tags: python, matrix, graph-theory, adjacency-matrix

Does anyone know an efficient algorithm to compute the [edge-adjacency matrix](https://www.cmm.ki.si/%7EFAMNIT-knjiga/wwwANG/The_Adjancency_Matrix-5.htm) (also known as the [line graph L(G)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_graph)) of a graph (G) starting from its traditional vertex-adjacency matrix?

By definition

> The edge-adjacency matrix E of G is a square and symmetric matrix whose elements eij are 1 if and only if edge i is adjacent to edge j. Two edges are adjacent if they are incidents to a common vertex.

Target transformation example. The nodes and edges’ roles are inversed in the new graph.

[image]

Comment: Hi! Interesting question. Here is the source code of networkx.line_graph, in case that helps: https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/_modules/networkx/generators/line.html#line_graph ; However, it starts from a list of edges rather than an adjacency matrix. The graph in your example would be represented as `[(n1, n2), (n2, n3), (n3, n4), (n3, n5)]`

Comment: BTW you can get the adjacency matrix from a networkx.Graph `G` into a numpy array with `m = nx.adjacency_matrix(G).toarray()`, and the edge list from the adjacency matrix with `edgelist = np.array(np.nonzero(m)).T`

Comment: Related: [Adjacency matrix of line graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73725687/adjacency-matrix-of-line-graph)